# Regex expression for Python single and mulitline comments

Tags: c#, python, regex, comments

I am going to make Python editor with C#. I want to write a regex expression for single-line and multiline comment for Python. I was trying to modify this expression for single-line and multiline comment in C#, but I couldn't do it, because in C# they use `/*` and `*/` so we can know which is start or end. But in Python they only use """(or ''') so we can't know which is start or end.

Regex expression for C#:

```
/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

Example of singleline and multiline in Python

Singleline:

```
''' comment comment '''

""" comment comment """
```

Multiline

```
''' comment comment
comment comment
'''

""" comment comment
comment comment
"""
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: My best guess is he wants to write a regex to capture singline and multiline comments in Python

Comment: Not sure you can do this with just a regex. It's going to be context sensitive. (e.g. `foo = '''text'''`, `# This is a comment '''`, `bar = "'''"`, etc.)

Comment: i want to capture python comments in python files and highlight them. so i want to know how to capture them with Regex expression in C#

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Is there a better way than regex?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *could* work: `/("""[^"]*+"""|'''[^']+'''|#[^\n]*)/` **except**...

While `#stuff` unambiguously denotes a comment, `'''this one'''` and `"""this
(next line)
other"""` are not necessarily single/multi-line comments, they are just strings. The triple (single/double) quotes notation is for strings that can be split over multiple lines.

For example this is valid Python code.
`s="""My name is Alice.
My name is Bob."""`

So is this.
`eggs("""spam, sausages,
spam, spam, spam""")`.

An accurate answer should take care to exclude at the very least the above two cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `("""|''')[\s\S]*?\1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6HdVq7/1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but if i use it, I got an error and  it says "unrecognized escape sequence". so i changed it "(\"\"\"|\'\'\')[\\s\\S]*?\\1" but now it is only working in single line.

Comment: you have escaped even single quotes `'`. See this [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jkimoG). it works for multiline as well